# How to create single stacked bar chart in MP Android?

Tags: android, android-canvas, mpandroidchart

I would like to achieve something like this:

[image: graph]

I managed to create a single stacked bar chart, but I can't move each stack label on right. Is it even possible?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Unfortunately this is not a tutorial site. You are welcome to ask specific question, yet "how to" is not usually one of these

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski maybe title is confusing, but I asked specific question at the end. Thanks